# C program not printing the Tensorflow version?

Tags: c, tensorflow

I am a newbie to C programming and want to use Tensorflow in C in windows for inference. I have downloaded from [Tensorflow Official C](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c) and my directory looks like below,

```
.
├── .vscode
├── include
    ├──tensorflow
│      ├── c
│      └── core
├── lib
├── test.c
```

Below is my `test.c` based on example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>
void main()
{
    printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
}
```

Below is my build command,

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -IC:\test\include -LC:\test\lib -g C:\test\test.c -ltensorflow -o C:\test\test.exe
```

GCC compiles successfully and when I run test.exe it prints nothing. I thought it could be a flush issue but it is not. Any support?

Comment: The error means it can't find the `libtensorflow.so` or `libtensorflow.a`. Where is that file located?

Comment: Okay I will try placing them. Quick question - Can I use C without these lib? Basically I cannot use DLL or .so in my existing tool and I thought C is without these libraries

Comment: No you absolutely cannot use it without the lib. The header file only contains the declarations of the functions and types. The actual  implementation is provided by the lib.

Comment: oh okay. Thanks. I added the lib and now it is compiling. But the line is not printing. I added a dummy printf("Test") before this printf and that is also not printing. Any idea? If I comment this printf, then Test is printing

Comment: The shell has a built-in `test` command.  It is being run instead of your program.  Try `./test` or `test.exe` to run your code.  More generally, do not call your test programs `test`.